# Calculating days since an event in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a weather data set. I am particularly interested in two columns which are cumulative precipitation and a date. My question is a simple one, though I am struggling to figure out the solution. Essentially I am wanting to determine days since precipitation. An example of the data is as follows:

WEATHER DATA

```
Pr  Date
40  8/8/2013
40  8/8/2013
40  8/9/2013
40  8/9/2013
41  8/10/2013
41  8/10/2013
```

In this example, if I know the last day it rained was 8/7, then 8/8 would have a value of 1 (days since precipitation), 8/9 would be 2, and 8/10 would go back to 0. I have multiple dates because of hourly recordings (I trimmed it down for this post). I've been trying to figure it out with conditional if|then statements, but I'm thinking VBA may be more appropriate here. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would the date go back to 0 on 8/10?
To find the difference between two dates you could use `=A1 - DATE(2012,8,7)`

Comment: You can learn the basics of VBA programming on this website: http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_tutorial.html I'd suggest looking at lessons 4-7 for the task you need to accomplish.

Comment: Do you have any breaks in the time data? i.e., does the column date have observations in consecutive days?

Comment: Bijan - It would go back to 0 because the cumulative precip went from 40 to 41, suggesting it rained on 8/10/2013, therefore it would be 0 days since precipitation.

Ross, thanks for the link. I will take a look at it. 

Andre, not sure if I am fully understanding your question. There are multiple observations in one day though. 24 to be exact. There shouldn't be any breaks in the time data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cell C2 to be equal 1 (or start where you wish by adjusting the C2 value), the formula below works in the example you provided. Type in C3:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,0,IF(B3=B2,C2,1+C2))
```

Drag the formula down. Explanation:

If precipitation from time i+next is different from i it comes back to zero --> there was rain.

If time i+next is equal i, then it compares the date d+next with d.

1. If they are equal hold the number of days without rain from previous cell.
2. If they are not, add 1 day* to the value inside previous cell.

*I'm assuming you have consecutive days from the following sentence:

> I have multiple dates because of hourly recordings